# javascript button in salesforce

Tags: javascript

I have developed an onclick javascript. I want to show some alert based on some conditions. How to implement this?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/24.0/apex.js")}
var carset = new sforce.SObject("Rfleet_Car_Set__c ");
carset.Id = '{!Rfleet_Car_Set__c.Id}';
var a = sforce.connection.query("select Name,Net_Price__c,
    (select Name,Net_Price__c,Price_HT__c from Services__r) 
        from Rfleet_Car_Set__c where id ='{!Rfleet_Car_Set__c.Id}'" ); 

var records = a.getArray("records");
var netPrice = records[0].Net_Price__c ;
 // get related services records for current carset record
var services = records[0].Services__r.getArray('records');
for (var i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
    var service = services[i];
    var price = service.Price_HT__c;
    alert(price );
    if(netPrice == null || price == null){
    alert('hello,please enter the valid value of netprice');
    } else {

    alert('yes,you have already entered the net price value');
    window.location.reload()
    }
}
```

My need is if Carset NetPrice=0 and any of the service Price_Ht is 0 ,then I want show "some message " msg.otherwise I

But now i have put this in for loop. So for every service record PriceHT is checked and alert is coming.Hoe to overcome this ?

Comment: Please update you question, what do you want to show otherwise ?

Comment: inside you for statement you have alert(price ); I think that could fix you issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this I was implemented like this in my org to show alert message  :-

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/resource/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery.min.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/resource/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/15.0/apex.js")} 

var flag = true; 
var tempId = "{!Contact.customer_id__c}"; 
var str1 = sforce.apex.execute("UpdateCustomer","CheckFunction",{ConId:"{!Contact.Id}"}); 
if(str1 == "false" ){ 
    var htmlContent2 = " <style>.dlgfixed{position:fixed !important;top:50px !important;right:0 !important;left:0 !important;z-index:99999 !important;width:400px !important;margin:auto !important;}</style><center><p><font size='3' color='#322A2A'><strong>The subdomain field value is missing in associated account </strong></font></p></center></br></br>"; 
    var html2 = '<div id="dialog2" style="display: none" title=" Update Customer">'+htmlContent2+'</div>'; 
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
    $j(function() { 
        $j('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"/>'); 
        $j('body').append(html2); 
        $j("#dialog2").dialog({ 
            autoOpen: true, 
            modal: true, 
            dialogClass: 'dlgfixed', 
            buttons: { 
                "Ok": function() { 
                    location.reload(true); 
                }   
            } 
        }); 
    }); 
    flag = false; 
} 
if(flag == true){ 
    var htmlContent1 = " <style>.dlgfixed{position:fixed !important;top:50px !important;right:0 !important;left:0 !important;z-index:99999 !important;width:400px !important;margin:auto !important;}</style><center><p><font size='3' color='#322A2A'><strong>Are you sure you would like to update the Customer information?</strong></font></p></center></br></br>"; 
    var html1 = '<div id="dialog1" style="display: none" title=" Update Customer Info">'+htmlContent1+'</div>'; 
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
    $j(function() { 
        $j('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"/>'); 
        $j('body').append(html1); 
        $j("#dialog1").dialog({ 
            autoOpen: true, 
            modal: true, 
            dialogClass: 'dlgfixed', 
            buttons: { 
                "Confirm": function() { 
                    // perform some valid action here
                    //alert(str); 
                    var htmlContent5 = " <style>.dlgfixed{position:fixed !important;top:50px !important;right:0 !important;left:0 !important;z-index:99999 !important;width:400px !important;margin:auto !important;}</style><center><p><font size='3' color='#322A2A'><strong>"+str+"</strong></font></p></center></br></br>"; 
                    var html5 = '<div id="dialog5" style="display: none" title="Add Contact">'+htmlContent5+'</div>'; 
                    var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
                    $j(function() { 
                        $j('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"/>'); 
                        $j('body').append(html5); 
                        $j("#dialog5").dialog({ 
                            autoOpen: true, 
                            modal: true, 
                            dialogClass: 'dlgfixed', 
                            buttons: { 
                                "Close": function() { 
                                    $j(this).dialog("close"); 
                                } 
                            } 
                        }); 
                    }); 
                    $j(this).dialog("close"); 
                }, 
                "Cancel": function() { 
                    $j(this).dialog("close"); 
                } 
            } 
        }); 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Surely you do not need duplicate inclusions of your scripts.

Answer (score -1):

I have a very simple solution for showing rich "alerts" on standard page layouts.
http://www.codebycody.com/2016/11/custom-html-dialog-box-on-standard-salesforce-page-layouts.html

Comment: If your link answers the question, please include the relevant content here.